# What Google Sheets formula should I use to average values that are not empty and are unique?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have the next two tables:

[Table 1, on sheet called "top1Data"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL56R.png)

[Table 2, on sheet called "top1An"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvptb.png)

I want to take all the unique champions from Table 1 and insert them into Table 2 (under Total), and then average their stats (kills, solokills).

Note that more champions can be added in the future, so it has to check for non-empty cells.

[You can find an editable copy of the Google Sheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s4Nc9v1OWEGniJv-nqwe099hf6qmOFSfSENFDE7pFNs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: Added a link to it to the bottom of the post. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell B3:

```
=query( 
  query( 
    C2:E, 
    "select C, sum(D), sum(E) 
     where C is not null 
     group by C", 
    1 
  ), 
  "select avg(Col2), avg(Col3) 
   label avg(Col2) '' , avg(Col3) '' ", 
  1 
)
```

Comment: Tried it on Table 2, cell B4 and got 0 as a result. I've added a link to the spreadsheet at the bottom of the post in case you want to check it directly.

Comment: Since the formula is in another sheet, you will have to add the source sheet name in the range reference. Replace `C2:E` with `top1Data!C2:E`. See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s4Nc9v1OWEGniJv-nqwe099hf6qmOFSfSENFDE7pFNs/edit#gid=1515770500).